# bigquery joining a field and json unnested resulted only left hand side table

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, left-join

Need help to get the select statement of normal text record and json unnest answers.

I am getting only left hand normal text record. Am I missing some thing?.

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jsonunnest(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(input).map(j=>JSON.stringify(j));
"""; 
WITH `Impact_JSON` AS (
  SELECT 
  Impact_Question_id,
  Impact_Question_text, json,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bdmp_id, DATE(Impact_Question_aktualisiert_am_ts)
      ORDER BY
        Impact_Question_aktualisiert_am_ts DESC) AS ROW

  FROM
  `<project.dataset.table` basetable

),
json_answers AS (

    SELECT

      regexp_replace(SPLIT(ANY_VALUE(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_antwort_id')),'_')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)], "[^0-9]+"," " ) AS Interview_ID,
       regexp_replace(SPLIT(ANY_VALUE(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_antwort_id')),'_')[SAFE_OFFSET(3)], "[^0-9]+"," " ) AS Quest_ID,
      
      STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_antwort_id')), ',\n')
      AS Impact_antwort_id,

      STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_antwort_daten_typ')),',\n') 
      AS Impact_reply_data_type,
      IFNULL(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_topic_text'), 'Empty') AS Impact_topic_text,
    
      IFNULL(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_reply_get'), 'Empty') AS Impact_reply_get,


    FROM `Impact_JSON`,
    UNNEST(jsonunnest(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.reply'))) Impact

    GROUP by 5,6

),

Impact_Question_id_TBL AS (

select Impact_Question_id from `Impact_JSON` AS C

) 

SELECT

Impact_Question_id

FROM 

`Impact_JSON` AS T

left join
  
json_answers as J

ON

(SAFE_CAST(J.Interview_ID as INT64)) 
=

T.Impact_Question_id
```

The left hand side records and right hand side records in same table should be captured.

Comment: Please provide a  minimal, reproducible example. We do not have your source and creating sample data is not our task.  Please run `select  Interview_ID , SAFE_CAST(Interview_ID as INT64)) from json_answers order by 1` and have a look that these values are also present in the other table.

Comment: Result of the query select  Interview_ID , SAFE_CAST(Interview_ID as INT64) AS Interview_ID_INT64 from json_answers order by 1                                                  
 Interview_ID Interview_ID_INT64

113006846     113006846

Comment: SELECT cfm_befragung_id from cfm_befragung_TBL

LEFT outer JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM json_answers  
 ) as I

-- SAFE_CAST(I.Interview_ID AS INT64) 

ON (I.Interview_ID = C.id )

Comment: Interview _id is 113006846

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect as output?

For me the udf did not work. Otherwise I generated some sample data and shorten your query for testing. This had been a good starting point for a question!

Also I changed the join to a full outer join.

For each dataset there is a number in column `Impact_Question_id`. There is `json` column containing a nested array data structure. The json data is unnested and group by the column `Impact_reply_get`. The first part of the column `Impact_antwort_id` is extracted and named `Interview_ID`. Because of the grouping, you select a random value. Then you join by this to the master table to the column `Impact_Question_id`.

The random selecting by `any_value` of the column `Impact_antwort_id` (`Interview_ID`) could be the issue for the mismatch. I would also group by this value and risk double matches.

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jsonunnest(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
try{
return [].concat(JSON.parse(input) || [] ).map(j=>JSON.stringify(j));
} catch(e) {return ["no",JSON.parse(input)]}
"""; 
WITH 
basetable as (Select row_number() over () Impact_Question_id,
"txt" as Impact_Question_text,
 json
#1 as bdmp_id,
#current_date() Impact_Question_aktualisiert_am_ts,
from unnest([ '{"reply":[{"Impact_antwort_id":"anytext_2","Impact_reply_get":"ok test 2"}]}','{"reply":[{"Impact_antwort_id":"anytext_3"}]}']) as json
),


`Impact_JSON` AS (
  SELECT 
  Impact_Question_id,
  Impact_Question_text, json,
  #ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bdmp_id, DATE(Impact_Question_aktualisiert_am_ts)
   #   ORDER BY
   #     Impact_Question_aktualisiert_am_ts DESC) AS ROW

  FROM
   basetable

),
json_answers AS (

    SELECT 
   

      regexp_replace(SPLIT(ANY_VALUE(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_antwort_id')),'_')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)], "[^0-9]+"," " ) AS Interview_ID,
   #    regexp_replace(SPLIT(ANY_VALUE(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_antwort_id')),'_')[SAFE_OFFSET(3)], "[^0-9]+"," " ) AS Quest_ID,
      
    #  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_antwort_id')), ',\n')
     # AS Impact_antwort_id,

      #STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_antwort_daten_typ')),',\n') 
   #   AS Impact_reply_data_type,
   #   IFNULL(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_topic_text'), 'Empty') AS Impact_topic_text,
    
      IFNULL(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Impact, '$.Impact_reply_get'), 'Empty') AS Impact_reply_get,

 string_agg(Impact) as impact_parsed_json,
    FROM `Impact_JSON`,
    UNNEST(jsonunnest(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.reply'))) Impact

    GROUP by 2 #5,6

)



SELECT

*

FROM 

`Impact_JSON` AS T

full join
  
json_answers as J

ON

(SAFE_CAST(J.Interview_ID as INT64)) 
=

T.Impact_Question_id
```